# Is it incorrect to say "lavo le mie mani" vs. the more common "mi lavo le mani"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, pronouns

Obviously it is not incorrect to say *lavo le mie mani* (c.f. [Salmi 26:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Salmi%2026%3A6-8&version=LND)), but *mi lavo le mani* (also *mi lavo la faccia*) is more common. Why is this?

Is this a special use of reflexive verbs to stand in for possessive adjectives. Can you also say *mi lavo la macchina* for *lavo la mia macchina* or is it only something that works for items that are related to (or owned by) the subject?

Comment: In `mi lavo le mani` there is no reflexive verb. `Mi` is *complemento di termine* and this construct is called *forma riflessiva apparente* ("seemingly reflexive verbal form"). `Mi lavo le mani` is structurally more similar to `mi compro la macchina` than to `lavo le mie mani`.
Anyway I appreciate this doesn't answer your question. I don't know why `lavo le mie mani` just sounds wrong. What is really weird is that saying `lavo le mie mani` kind of implies to my ears that you wash *your* hands as opposed to somebody else's.

Comment: To confuse your ideas even further, personally I don't think we say `mi lavo la macchina` (somewhat acceptable) nor `lavo la mia macchina` (very, very strange). What you usually hear is `lavo la macchina`.

Comment: @gd1 Interesting, I had never heard of the *forma riflessiva apparente* ... could it be also that it is a *riflessivo indiretto* as in "Federica si pulisce le mani" referenced in this [entry](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-riflessivi_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/).

Comment: *Forma riflessiva indiretta* and *forma riflessiva apparente* are the same stuff AFAIK

Comment: Out of special situations when one looks for a poetic effect or, as said above, to emphasise something, *lavo le mie mani* is completely un-idiomatic and sounds like a bad translation from English.

Comment: What DaG says. I don't think there is another answer than "it is idiomatic". Both *mi lavo le mani* and *lavo le mie mani* are well-formed, grammatically correct Italian sentences. Yet, virtually everyone uses the first form rather than the second.

Comment: *lavo le mie mani* just sounds weird, don't use it as people will assume you don't know italian. 
A general rule I just made up: *mi lavo whatever* should be used in relation to your body parts, it's very common to hear that. Not your car. You wash THE car.

Comment: There is plenty of expressions in which a possessive is used in English but not in Italian. For instance, *fai i compiti* vs. *Do your homework*, *mangia la verdura* vs *eat your vegetables*, *prendi(ti) tempo* vs *take your time*.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be bold and state that, while “lavo le mie mani” and “lavo le mani” are not technically agrammatical (nouns and verbs agree as they should and so on), they are so unusual with respect to “mi lavo le mani” that – if we agree that the rules are made by the actual usage and not by some combinatorics of morphological items – the former are plain wrong, in the sense that they attract the attention of the listener to the phrasing rather than to what is being said, and as such are either mistakes or poetic choices.

To give at least a statistical basis to the above, we may compare the [Google Ngrams graphs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lavo%20le%20mani%2Cme%20ne%20lavo%20le%20mani%2Bmi%20lavo%20le%20mani&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clavo%20le%20mani%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28me%20ne%20lavo%20le%20mani%20%2B%20mi%20lavo%20le%20mani%29%3B%2Cc0) for “lavo le mani” with those for “me ne lavo le mani” and for “mi lavo le mani“ added together, and see that the two graphs virtually coincide. “lavo le mie mani”, on the other hand, doesn't even show up.

(I am grateful to Sklivvz for our exchange of opinions on this.)

Comment: Totally agree with DaG.
I don't know why many people fail to understand that human languages are not designed top-down as computer protocols but they are "created" bottom-up on a very slow process taking thousand and thousand of years. So it's very common to find exceptions, tons of way to say the same thing and even arbitrary choices and preferences regarding one sentence construct over an another. Maybe one sentence sounds "right" and another sounds plain "wrong" just because the former is actually used by people and the latter is not used.

Comment: @Gianluca: Welcome to Italian.SE! This is not a discussion forum, and your “answer” is not really one. Nevertheless, I think it can be edited to become a good answer: please have a try.

Comment: I would also add that we *tend* to accept more oddities and absurd sentences when we answer questions on Italian.SE, things that we would possibly never have said when speaking spontaneously with each other. *Thinking about it* is what sometimes fails us.

Answer (score 1):

When washing your own body parts, it is appropriate to use the [reflexive version](http://italian.about.com/library/verb/blverb_lavarsi.htm) of the verb: *lavarsi* instead of *lavare*, or often simply omit the specification. It's not very usual to wash someone else's body parts.

> Lavarsi le mani, "Lavati i capelli!", Mi lavai i denti

or (less frequently)

> Lavare le mani, "Lava i capelli!", Lavai i denti

You can always use the active form and specify whose body parts you are washing

> Lavare le proprie mani, "Lava i tuoi capelli!", Lavai i miei denti

However, since the version without the adjective is very common, this version sounds overwrought and is seldom used unless you are washing someone else's body parts.

> Lavare le mani di qualcuno, "Lava i suoi capelli!", Lavai i suoi denti

In which case you can also use the form with the joined complement, like so

> Lavarle le mani, "Lavagli i capelli!", Le lavai i denti

However you can not specify both: the presence of the reflexive form of the verb and the adjective are redundant and are not correct Italian.

> Lavarsi le proprie mani, "Lavale i suoi capelli!", Mi lavai i miei denti

Comment: Not going to downvote of course, but 1) `lavarsi le mani` is not reflexive, let alone `lavagli i capelli`, 2) `lava i suoi capelli!` is pretty bad unless you are implying something very specific (`suoi` as opposed to `tuoi`, for example), 3) your examples that "simply omit the specification," i.e. `lava i capelli` and especially `lavai i denti`, are indeed weird.

Comment: I've added a reference for point 1. I don't know what to make about point 2 or point 3. Regarding point 2, I think it's the only correct translation of "wash their hair!", so I don't find it weird, and regarding point 3, I normally tell my son "lava i capelli" and ask him: "hai lavato i denti?". It's perfectly normal, common Italian, I am not sure what you find weird in it.

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are subject to opinions of course - I find that `lava i suoi capelli!` implies `suoi` as opposed to `tuoi` or anybody else's - , point 1 is simple as "it is not reflexive."

Comment: Point 1 is fixed, I'll keep the rest as is, though. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks but it is not fixed IMO. In your whole post, there isn't a single reflexive verb and that includes `lavarsi le mani`.

Comment: @gd1 I've linked a reference, did you read it? it specifically mentions washing one's body parts as reflexive.

Comment: If it does, it's wrong, and I wouldn't be surprised given the source. :) Please read my first comment to the OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24570/discussion-between-sklivvz-and-gd1).